# Cannot register blueprints with Flask Restplus

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

So when all this is put into one file, the webapp works as well as the API and I am able to see the documentation. I wish to separate the API into a separate file. However I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    app.register_blueprint(GetResource)
  File "/home/jj/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 66, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jj/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1102, in register_blueprint
    if blueprint.name in self.blueprints:
AttributeError: type object 'GetResource' has no attribute 'name'
```

Here is the example code at `project/main.py`:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
from flask import Flask, render_template
from datetime import timedelta
from utils.api_methods import GetResource

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION = 'full'
app.register_blueprint(GetResource)
app.secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=1)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and here is project/utils/api_methods.py:

```
from flask import request
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, make_response
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api


blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
api = Api(
    blueprint, doc='/', version='1.0',
    title='Testing Blueprints',
    description="Try the API")
api.namespaces = []
ns = api.namespace('', description='test')
parser1 = api.parser()
parser1.add_argument(
    'Path',
    location='headers',
    help='Path to file or directory',
    required=True
)


@ns.route('/resources')
@api.route('/resources')
@api.doc(parser=parser1)
class GetResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        ...
        return jsonify({'SUCCESS': 'endpoint accessed'})
```

Comment: Can you share the full error message?

Comment: sure added an edit above

Comment: I submitted an edit for the title and the last line of your code (which gives a syntax error). Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the *blueprint*, not the resource class, as the name of the method `register_blueprint` implies.

```py
from utils.api_methods import blueprint

...

app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
```

Comment: I had actually tried that at as well. However it results in a No module named 'utils.api_methods' with or without an __init__.py inside of the utils directory.

Comment: @m.a.d.cat It should be `__init__.py`, not `init.py`. Did you try that too?

Comment: sorry that's what I meant... the comments didn't display underscores. Let me edit the post and update the code

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce that error. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: It was your original answer.. thanks. I was trying to import the class instead of the blueprint. In the middle of that I had messed up my `__init__.py` somewhere.